# Show Only The Value in First Text Box in SSRS Grouping

Tags: reporting-services, expression, ssrs-2008-r2

Hopefully the title explains what I am looking to do adequately.  I have a report is row grouped by Survey, then Customer ID, and then Response ID (which shows what instance of the survey the customer took). And in the Detail grouping, the Questions and Answer of each survey is displayed, in addition to the Agent ID who gave the survey.

Here is a screenshot of my report layout and preview:

[image: Report Preview]

Under the Donation Survey, each Customer only has to answer one question and the Agent ID is displayed - if available.

But I am having an issue on surveys that have multiple questions and answers, the Agent ID is displayed for each question.  Is there an expression I can use to only display the Agent ID for the first question?

I have tried different variations of the RowNumber expression, such as:

```
=IIF(RowNumber(Fields!ResponsesID.Value)=1,Fields!AgentID.Value,"")
```

To only display one time, but I have been unsuccessful so far.  Could anyone offer a suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the scope of survey group to the RowNumber function

```
=IIF((RowNumber("surveyGroup") =1),Fields!AgentID.Value,"")
```